# Embedded font in Alert font-family property doesn't working in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm using Flex 4. I'm trying to apply a embedded font in all Alert components of the application, to get the same style that all the app, of course.

I code in my CSS file:

```
@font-face
{ 
fontFamily: "Trebuchet MS";
src: url("resources/Trebuchet MS.ttf");
embedAsCFF: true;
}
mx|Alert{   
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
} 
s|ButtonBase, s|TextBase, s|TextInput, mx|Label{
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
color:"#000000";
}
```

The font-family worked to all componentes, but not to the Alert component. In alert the text message and title got unvisible. If I change to other font-family it works correctly, just the embedded font doesn't work on Alert component. Anyone got this problem?

Obs: The embedded font worked in all the app, just the Alert no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that Alert is a MX component, not a Spark component.
MX components don't handle Device 4 fonts by default.

To make it work, you have to change the textFieldClass for MX components :

```
mx|global
{
    textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETextField");
}
```

Comment: Wow!! Man, it works perfectly! But I don't understood what I have done.. I would like to understand, could you send me a link about this?

Comment: Yes, here you go :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0FA8AEDB-C69F-4f19-ADA5-AA5757217624.html
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Font+Embedding+Reprise
http://www.webappsolution.com/wordpress/2011/01/20/getting-spark-mx-components-to-use-embedded-fonts/
http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/flex-font-embedding-with-spark-and-halo-made-easy/
http://blogs.adobe.com/tlf/2008/11/embedded-font-subsetting-using.html

Comment: i have a somewhat similar question, do you think you could shed insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766319/embedded-font-wont-work-in-flex-mobile-actionbar

Comment: Or use the new `spark.components.Alert` introduced in Flex 4.10 - because that CSS-setting breaks the `ColorPicker`: Error: 'restrict' is not implemented in FTETextField.