# embedded font won't work in Flex mobile ActionBar

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, flex-actionbar

i've got a few fonts embedded and am using them in my mobile application, and they are all working, except for the ones i try to use for the "ActionBar". They work everywhere else, and substituting `"Comic Sans MS"` for `"titleCGF"` changes it to Comic Sans. So why won't it work with my custom fontFamily?

```
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @font-face {
            src: url("assets/Comic_Book.ttf");
            fontFamily: comic;
            embedAsCFF: false;
        }
/******************************
        @font-face{
            src: url("assets/CGF_Locust_Resistance.ttf");
            fontFamily: titleCGF;
            embedAsCFF: false;
        }
        @font-face{
            src: url("assets/CGF_Locust_Resistance.ttf");
            fontFamily: titleCGF;
            embedAsCFF: true;
        }
**********************************/
        .titleStyle{
            fontFamily: titleCGF;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .comicMessage{
            fontFamily: titleCGF;
            color: #838689;
            fontSize: 14;
        }
        s|IconItemRenderer{
            fontFamily: comic;
            color: #FEBA03;
            fontSize:18;
        }
        s|ActionBar{
            defaultButtonAppearance: beveled;
            accentColor: #FEBA03;
        }
        s|ActionBar #titleDisplay{
            fontFamily: "titleCGF";

        }
    </fx:Style>
```

this is what i get:

[image: FontView]

EDIT: i tried to make my own skin, and part of the pre-written code is this:

```
<!-- SkinParts
name=titleGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
name=actionGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
name=navigationGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
name=titleDisplay, type=spark.core.IDisplayText, required=false
-->
```

when i try to define something like the first three, `<s:Group .../>`, it works fine. But nothing shows up for spark.core.IDisplayText. ie, `<s:IDisplayText .../>` yeilds nothing...

Comment: +1 from me.  One of my customers was having similar font issues w/ Flex Mobile and I was never able to track down exactly what; but it appeared some components picked up embedded fonts and others did not.  I believe our custom components inherited said issues from the Flex Framework; so I bet you're running into something similar.

Comment: crud :/ the worst part is how inconsistent it makes the app look. Using any other than system fonts isn't entirely practical if you can't customize all of them.

Comment: Why do you have the fontFamily for the actionbar wrapped in quotation marks? Also, you could try to add that font as default for your whole application under the `global` selector to see if that works.  If not, I would look into the ActionBar code/skin.

Comment: for some reason, the only way to get even a default font to apply to ActionBar is to wrap it in quotes. And i just tried, and added the font through Flex, still no luck :(

Comment: I ran into this and finally found a work around, I'll try to dig it up - but I know it can be done!

Comment: I had some issues when I had multiple fonts for the values like so, "fontFamily: Courier, Courier New, Andalus;". It wouldn't work on some devices. I tried adding quotes to some and then all and then removing fonts with spaces and it was inconsistent. Finally, I made multiple declarations, .myStyle { font-family:Andalus } .myStyle { font-family:Courier New } .myStyle {font-family: Courier } one after another. That seemed to work. The order is important. The last one declared wins. Hope that makes sense and helps someone. Quotes might also matter when the font name has spaces but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can get a list of all embedded fonts in your application and name and styles used by your component using this class, https://github.com/monkeypunch3/flexcapacitor/blob/master/MainLibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/utils/MiniInspector.as. Set showStyleInheritanceInformation, showEmbeddedFontInformation, showGlobalStyles, showUniversalStyles and includeEmbeddedFontDetails to true. Then command + click on the Text field in your app.

Comment: Ahhh. I just found out that I have to set embedAsCFF to false on mobile because the skin uses StylableTextField.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of embedding fonts twice, once with embedAsCFF=false and again using embedAsCFF=true. View the full explanation at http://blogs.adobe.com/jasonsj/2011/08/embedding-fonts-in-flex-mobile-projects.html.

Edit 1: Fixed font file name

```
/* StyleableTextField, regular */
@font-face {
    src: url("assets/COMIC.TTF");
    fontFamily: "comic";
    embedAsCFF: false;
}

/* StyleableTextField, bold */
@font-face {
    src: url("assets/COMICBD.TTF");
    fontFamily: "comic";
    fontWeight: bold;
    embedAsCFF: false;
}

/* Label, regular */
@font-face {
    src: url("assets/COMIC.TTF");
    fontFamily: "comicCFF";
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

/* Label, bold */
@font-face {
    src: url("assets/COMICBD.TTF");
    fontFamily: "comicCFF";
    fontWeight: bold;
    embedAsCFF: true;
}

s|Label
{
    fontFamily: "comicCFF";
}

s|ActionBar
{
    fontFamily: "comic";
}

s|LabelItemRenderer
{
    fontFamily: "comic";
}
```

Comment: the key is making sure each `fontWeight` is specified the same. The default is `bold`, and my font was `normal`. added that, and it was fine! thanks!!

Comment: Can you overload the font family name? For example, could you use "comic" for both embeddedAsCFF true and embeddedAsCFF false declarations?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for mx buton in flex4 what I did was mentioned font weight in both place as bold. Then it got working.

```
<fx:Style>

@font-face
        { 
            src: url("assets/fonts/Quasari1.ttf");
            fontFamily: msd;
            embedAsCFF: true; 
            fontWeight : bold;

        }
mx|Button{   
            fontFamily: msd;
            fontSize:22;
            color: red;
            fontWeight : bold;
            textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETextField"); 
        } 
</fx:Style>
<mx:Button label="submit" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that Button on Flex 3 had this issue, because its default font was bold, and many people did not think to embed the bold version of the font.  Is it possible that the default action bar mobile skin uses bold/italic/something else and that you need to either make your own skin or embed both?

===========new stuff below==============

I don't have FB 4.5 installed on this machine yet, but I think you can right click in the package explorer and select New>Mobile As3 skin (or words to that effect).  The dialog will ask you what component you want to select, and you should browse for action bar.  I haven't done this (as I haven't needed mobile development yet), but it will probably create an as3 file with most of what you need to get started.

You'll probably find the code you need to edit in updateDisplayList and it will refer to titleDisplay.

HTH;

Amy

Comment: nope. i have confirmed that it is embedded correctly, and still no luck :/ how would i go about building my own skin?

Comment: i did this, and i think i might have gotten closer to the issue. It built me a base file (in .mxml), and included this:

`<!-- SkinParts
 name=titleGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
 name=actionGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
 name=navigationGroup, type=spark.components.Group, required=false
 name=titleDisplay, type=spark.core.IDisplayText, required=false
 -->`

thing is, when you try to define something like `<s:Group .../>` for the first three, you're fine. but nothing appears for `<s:IDisplayText .../>` or `<s:core .../>`

Comment: IDisplayText is an Interface, which allows you more freedome for which Component you use there.  I believe Label implements IDisplayText, and probably RichEditableText.  Check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a separate copy of the font with embedAsCFF: true; and apply that to the label in the skin and it will work.  I can't remember the reasoning for it off hand (deadline=wtfever), but I know this solved this exact issue for me.

True story.   =)

P.s. make sure the bold / italics are correct in the style as well.

Comment: i modified my  code above to reflect the change you suggested, but it still won't show up :/ did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the ActionBar tag, to remove the bold styling:

```
creationComplete="event.currentTarget.titleDisplay.setStyle('fontWeight', 'normal')"
```

If that works, then you can try a better solution like extending the ActionBar class, or embedding the font in a bold style as well.

Comment: this didn't have any effect :/ i also tried to set the fontWeight as normal in the `<fx:Style>` tag, with no effect either.

Comment: OK, try this.  Remove the font-face block with `embedAsCFF: true`.  Then, add `fontWeight: normal` to the `s|ActionBar #titleDisplay` block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stylesheet that i use to style mobile apps (Action Bar, TextAreas, Buttons, and Labels.)  It's compiled from blogs and forum posts.

```
/* CSS file */
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

@font-face
{ 
    src: url("styles/acmesab.TTF"); 
    fontFamily: comicStrip; 
    embedAsCFF: false; 
}

@font-face
{ 
    src: url("styles/acmesab.TTF"); 
    fontFamily: comicStrip2; 
    embedAsCFF: true; 
}

s|ActionBar
{
    chromeColor: #EEEEEE;
    titleAlign: center;
    defaultButtonAppearance: beveled;
}

s|ActionBar #titleDisplay
{
    fontFamily: comicStrip;
    fontWeight: normal;
    color: #000000;
    textShadowColor: #FFFFFF;
}

s|ActionBar.beveled s|Group#actionGroup s|Button 
{
    fontFamily: comicStrip;
    fontWeight: normal;
    color: #000000;
    textShadowColor: #FFFFFF;
}

s|ActionBar.beveled s|Group#navigationGroup s|Button 
{
    fontFamily: comicStrip;
    fontWeight: normal;
    color: #000000;
    textShadowColor: #FFFFFF;
}

.textArea
{
    fontFamily: comicStrip;
    fontSize: 14;
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin");
}

.button
{
    fontFamily: comicStrip;
    fontSize: 14;
    fontWeight: normal;
    skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.ButtonSkin");
}

.label
{
    fontFamily: comicStrip2;
    fontSize: 14;
    fontWeight: normal;
}
```